# Google Maps: Distinguishing Enter Click Source

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm trying to distinguish when someone using a search box was assisted by the google maps places autocomplete, and when they have simply entered text.

I am able to detect the pressing of the enter button, but I cannot tell the difference between them entering data on their own, or selecting an item from the autocomplete list.

I've noticed that when an item is highlighted using the up and down arrows, it is given a class of `pac-item-selected`, but the event listener seems to fire AFTER the class is removed due to the keystroke.

I have tried using both standard jQuery listeners, as well as attaching to those provided by the google framework.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(input, 'keydown', function(e) { 
  if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
    //always comes back 0
    alert($('.pac-item-selected').length);
  }
});

$('#searchproperties').keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    //also comes back 0
    alert($('.pac-item-selected').length);
  }
});
```

How can I tell if someone has used the up and down arrows to select an item from autocomplete when they hit enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply check the `place`-property of the Autocomplete(via `getPlace()`).

When it only contains a single property `name` (equal to the value of the `<input/>`)and no other properties like e.g. `place_id` you may assume that the user has entered the text.